# Get dimensions from a flash file (.swf) in pure-Python

Tags: python, flash

How would I extract the dimensions (width and height) from a flash file?

I intend on using this code inside a webapp hosted on Google App Engine, so libs that are no pure-python will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never actually used it, but I suspect that the [hexagonit.swfheader](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hexagonit.swfheader/1.0.1) module would work for your purposes. It is pure python, and tiny (full source including a test-case is a 4KB tarball.) I was created for more or less exactly what you are doing.

I should mention that it claims to be licensed under the GPL, so that may be a problem. Regardless, all it is actually doing is extracting some bytes from the header of the SWF file and interpreting them. It would be reasonably easy to rewrite if you were worried about licensing issues.