# Reading in a xml file and regex matching to find dimensions: Nonetype error

Tags: python, regex, svg

I've been working on a project taking in .svg files and finding their dimensions. Instead of converting them to png, or using pysvg see ([Best way of Getting Swf File Dimensions with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272806/best-way-of-getting-swf-file-dimensions-with-python))  I am not trying to simply scan the xml for the dimensions.

I've been using open("thefile").read() previously and I cannot see why this code is not working. Is it an issue with my regex?

An example of what an xml file might look like is this:

```
str: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="25.6px" width="74.9px"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5)">
    <path d="M71.3 0.15 Q73.9 0.75 73.9 4.0 L73.9 20.6 Q73.9 24.6 69.9 24.6 L4.0 24.6 Q0.9 24.6 0.2 22.2 L0.0 20.6 0.0 4.0 0.2 2.4 Q0.7 0.6 2.6 0.15 L4.0 0.0 69.9 0.0 71.3 0.15" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
    <path d="M71.3 0.15 L69.9 0.0 4.0 0.0 2.6 0.15 Q0.7 0.6 0.2 2.4 L0.0 4.0 0.0 20.6 0.2 22.2 Q0.9 24.6 4.0 24.6 L69.9 24.6 Q73.9 24.6 73.9 20.6 L73.9 4.0 Q73.9 0.75 71.3 0.15" fill="none" stroke="#8e8e8e" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The code where the error occurs:

```
    x=re.findall("width=\"[^\"]*",svgF)[0]
```

my variable x is found and is equal to 74.9px in this case. Exactly what I've been looking for. I just don't see where the error is coming from. If I just allow the error to occur the data I want is extracted. Any ideas?

The error:

> Error evaluating: thread_id: pid54226_seq2
>   frame_id: 140505356028928
>   scope: EXPRESSION
>   attrs: svgF
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715/pysrc/pydevd_vars.py", line 422, in resolveCompoundVariable
>       return resolver.getDictionary(var)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getDictionary'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG is XML document, so you shall use standard tools for XML. Regexps are not serving very well in these situations.

Following example uses xpath and `lxml` library (install it first)

```
>>> xmlstr = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
... <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="25.6px" width="74.9px"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...   <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5)">
...     <path d="M71.3 0.15 Q73.9 0.75 73.9 4.0 L73.9 20.6 Q73.9 24.6 69.9 24.6 L4.0 24.6 Q0.9 24.6 0.2 22.2 L0.0 20.6 0.0 4.0 0.2 2.4 Q0.7 0.6 2.6 0.15 L4.0 0.0 69.9 0.0 71.3 0.15" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
...     <path d="M71.3 0.15 L69.9 0.0 4.0 0.0 2.6 0.15 Q0.7 0.6 0.2 2.4 L0.0 4.0 0.0 20.6 0.2 22.2 Q0.9 24.6 4.0 24.6 L69.9 24.6 Q73.9 24.6 73.9 20.6 L73.9 4.0 Q73.9 0.75 71.3 0.15" fill="none" stroke="#8e8e8e" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.0"/>
...   </g>
... </svg>"""
...
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> svg = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
>>> svg
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg at 0x7f7d180d2638>
>>> svg.xpath("//@width")
['74.9px']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape double quotes inside character class. You need to give a regex which matches only `74.9px` because another `width` is available in your input.

```
>>> import re
>>> xmlstr = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
...  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="25.6px" width="74.9px"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5)">
...      <path d="M71.3 0.15 Q73.9 0.75 73.9 4.0 L73.9 20.6 Q73.9 24.6 69.9 24.6 L4.0 24.6 Q0.9 24.6 0.2 22.2 L0.0 20.6 0.0 4.0 0.2 2.4 Q0.7 0.6 2.6 0.15 L4.0 0.0 69.9 0.0 71.3 0.15" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
...      <path d="M71.3 0.15 L69.9 0.0 4.0 0.0 2.6 0.15 Q0.7 0.6 0.2 2.4 L0.0 4.0 0.0 20.6 0.2 22.2 Q0.9 24.6 4.0 24.6 L69.9 24.6 Q73.9 24.6 73.9 20.6 L73.9 4.0 Q73.9 0.75 71.3 0.15" fill="none" stroke="#8e8e8e" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.0"/>
...    </g>
...  </svg>"""
>>> x=re.findall(r' width="([^"]*)', xmlstr)
>>> x
['74.9px']
```